# Retain cells in UITableView in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cell

`UITableView` by default reuse cells. But in my case some cells have a `UITextField` object and I don't want to loose its value when the cell is reused. The table has few rows so I can handle all the cells in memory.

Example of code I currently use:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "TPAddressInfoTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: InfoCellIdentifier)
        ...

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let item = items[indexPath.row]
        switch item.appearance {
        case .textWithTitle:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: InfoCellIdentifier) as! TPAddressInfoTableViewCell
            return cell
        case .picker:
            ...
```

How to retain such cells correctly? Linking `UITextFieldDelegate` of each cell to current `UIViewController` seems to be extra in this case.

Comment: you should use model to hold values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Don't retain cells**.

Save all values of the UI elements of the cell in the data model and restore the values in `cellForRow`.

For example pass the corresponding model item to the cell in `cellForRow` and save the text field string in a property when it changes.
Alternatively use a callback closure to update the property in the controller.

Comment: 1)why shouldn't I retain cells? Dequeue mechanism is made for cases when there are a lot of cells. But in my case sometimes all the cells are visible and so they are all separate objects and no one from them is reused
2)callback to view controller causes you should save indexPath inside cell (to check which textField user change), link each text field delegate to view controller and then in callback you use indexPath to find the data you need to update.
2.2)"pass model item to the cell" - the only problem remains is what if you don't need to handle each symbol user inputs into textField.

Comment: 1) Because it's bad practice. The cell is supposed only to display the content. If the table view is static use static cells and outlets 2) When using a callback closure the text field delegate is connected to the **cell** and the index path is captured in `cellForRow`.

Comment: 1)static cells are available with storyboard only. Why not storyboard - what if I need an undefined amount of static cells with unpredictable item order? Or what if a lot of cells looks like the same? I don't want to create each similar cell manually 2)cellForRow belongs to `UITableDataSource`, not cell. So the result dataflow: viewController -> cell -> textField -> cell -> viewController. In the same time if the cells are static then viewController creates cell with inner content once and reads the result values when necessary only.